# Unable to resolve .NET Framework dependency in VS2017 csproj

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, asp.net-core, csproj

I am trying to use a WCF service, a .NET framework in a .NET core project.
I included the service as a project reference in the .NET core project, as you can see in the .csproj settings.

VS2017 complains that the service needs `System.ServiceModel assemble reference.` I tried to add `System.ServiceModel` but it has the following error:

> Error Unable to resolve 'System.ServiceModel (>= 4.0.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win7-x64)'.

I tried to add it in the csproj file as the following:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net462'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel" Version="4.0.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here is the whole csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net462</TargetFrameworks>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <AssemblyName>SimpleTokenProvider.Test</AssemblyName>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <PackageId>SimpleTokenProvider.Test</PackageId>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="Views;Areas\**\Views">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Services\Services.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\SimpleTokenProvider\SimpleTokenProvider.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp1.1'">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility" Version="1.0.1-rc2-24027" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net462'">
  <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel" Version="4.0.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: System.ServiceModel is not a package reference.